# Eclipse CDT C++ enum "could not be resolved"

Tags: c++, eclipse, enums, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing a game in Eclipse CDT in C++/OpenGL, and it compiles and runs just fine, but for some reason an enum I'm declaring (SCREEN_MAIN_MENU) gets underlined in red squiggles and highlighting it says Symbol SCREEN_MAIN_MENU could not be resolved. This is a blatant lie, how do I get Eclipse to recognize it?

Screens.h:

```
#ifndef SCREENS_H
#define SCREENS_H

enum {
SCREEN_MAIN_MENU,
SCREEN_LOADING,
SCREEN_GAME
};

class Screen{
public:
    static void change(int screen);
    static void render();
};

#endif
```

Screens.cpp:

```
#include "screens.h"
#include "gui.h"
#include "global.h"

extern Global global;

void Screen::change(int screen){
    global.screen = screen;
}

void Screen::render(){
if(global.screen == SCREEN_MAIN_MENU){ //HERE ARE THE RED SQUIGGLES!!!??
    global.text_renderer.print("Sidona", global.screen_width/2-40,
    global.screen_height-25);
    Gui::render();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may be caused by a bug in Eclipse CDT:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356057

Try to rebuild the index (Right click on the project -> Index -> Rebuild)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a named type for the enum?

i.e.

```
enum SCREEN_TYPE {  SCREEN_MAIN_MENU, SCREEN_LOADING, SCREEN_GAME };
```

Comment: yes, I've tried that and I've also tried typedef enum {...} SCREEN_TYPE and both cause the same problem

Comment: however if I do as you suggest, and then when I use the enum i replace SCREEN_MAIN_MENU with SCREEN_TYPE::SCREEN_MAIN_MENU the red squiggles disappear EVEN THOUGH THAT IS NOT VALID C++ CODE!?

Comment: no, it will no longer compile if I do that, even though eclipse seems to think it will.

Comment: @EricB If you use the suggestion in this answer, then you define a new type `SCREEN_TYPE` which indeed is used as `SCREEN_TYPE::SCREEN_MAIN_MENU`. That is valid C++.

Comment: only if I define SCREEN_TYPE as class with a static method, or a namespace. a named enum cannot be accessed with ::, at least not with g++ which is what i'm using. Either that or I'm doing something completely wrong but I don't know what it is.

Comment: if you attempt to compile SCREEN_TYPE a = SCREEN_TYPE::SCREEN_MAIN_MENU for example, it will give a compiler error: SCREEN_TYPE is not a class or namespace.

Comment: @EricB Sorry it seems I made a mistake. Correct syntax would be `enum SCREEN_TYPE {  SCREEN_MAIN_MENU, SCREEN_LOADING, SCREEN_GAME }; SCREEN_TYPE a = SCREEN_GAME;`.

Comment: Yes, this compiles but Eclipse still gives red squiggles. I have solved the problem though. I compiled the project on Windows, then checked it in to svn and checked it back out on Linux, and the squiggles went away. I don't know why.