# __cplusplus compiler directive defined and not defined

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with eclipse CDT.
Where i am having a C++ project that uses the C FatFs library. I'm trying to implement the fatfs files.
Question: In multiple files i'm adding

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" 
{ 
#endif 

// code..

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

wrapper. But for some reason, in the one .h file _cplusplus is defined, and in the other .h file the `__cplusplus` is not defined.

Any suggestions?
Can send screenshot for clarification.

Comment: I assume that in the real code you are clear about the number of underscores in __cplusplus?

Comment: Yes, i have an example where two different .h files are using the same code: __cplusplus. One is defined, one is not.

Comment: Do you really have `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `extern "C" {` on the same line?

Comment: No. Three lines. It would have been quicker if i could've linked an image in.

Comment: @RobbeVanAssche: It's always better to copy-and-paste the actual code.

Comment: @Keith: Will do more example code in the future. But i like to keep it simple, so my application doesn't clutter the actual question..

Comment: Or in fact a self-contained _testcase_. It baffles me that nobody does this. How can you debug your code without a testcase?!?!

Comment: @Lightness: I can send you a .zip file with the eclipse project in. But i'm not sure you want to put your time into figuring out embedded stm32 stuff..

Comment: @RobbeVanAssche: The best approach is not to show us your entire application. Just trim it down to a minimal test case that illustrates the problem, and copy-and-paste that into your question. Read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @RobbeVanAssche: I don't think you understand what I meant by _testcase_. http://sscce.org You should not be debugging individual language features by examining the entire contents of your entire real-world application. That's just silly! Divide and conquer, my friend.

Comment: @Lightness: Thanks for one more abbreviation in my belt ;). No, seriously: i now understand what you mean. I'll try and do this in the future. Maybe good with an online compiler then ? It seems that eclipse has some strange bugs that occur from one time to another. Like that it doesn't recognize typedef bool.. That makes it hard to see if it was a manmade programming error or just a quirk..

Comment: @RobbeVanAssche: This is a perfect example of the sort of quirk that can be very quickly isolated by making a testcase. Then in one feel swoop you've just divided your possible causes down to like 5%. And then we don't have to do that for you. :)

Comment: @Lightness: i found the quirk just now. Learned a lot by this thread. Thanks for everything! Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866873/eclipse-cdt-c-enum-could-not-be-resolved?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: [Combining C++ and C — how does `#ifdef __cplusplus` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789553)

> `extern "C"` doesn't really change the way that the compiler reads the
>   code. If your code is in a .c file, it will be compiled as C, if it is
>   in a .cpp file, it will be compiled as C++ (unless you do something
>   strange to your configuration).
>
> What `extern "C"` does is affect linkage. C++ functions, when compiled,
>   have their names mangled -- this is what makes overloading possible.
>   The function name gets modified based on the types and number of
>   parameters, so that two functions with the same name will have
>   different symbol names.
>
> Code inside an `extern "C"` is still C++ code. There are limitations on
>   what you can do in an `extern "C"` block, but they're all about linkage.

Also, you probably want *two* `#ifdef __cplusplus`s:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" { 
#endif 
    // ...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Otherwise, your C code will never see your definitions.

Comment: So example: i have header foo.h. I include header foo.h into foo.c and bar.cpp. In the first case, the header is processed by the c compiler and in the second case, the header is processed by the c++ compiler ?

Comment: It is the same compiler, just running in different modes. So yes, `__cplusplus` will not be defined when compiling `foo.c` by default because that file gets compiled in C mode instead of in C++ mode. Unless you force the compiler to compile it in C++ mode, which some compilers do provide an option for.

Answer (score 5):

Whether `__cplusplus` is defined or not depends on how the file that includes the header is being compiled. If the file is being compiled as C source (`.c`) it will not be defined. if the file is being compiled as C++ source (`.cpp`, `.cc`, or any other extension associated as a C++ source file) then `__cplusplus` will be defined.

Double check the file extensions and if necessary the settings in your project to ensure that the files are being compiled correctly.

Comment: But it is a header file. Does the compilation of the header file depends on whether it is included in a .c or .cpp file ? What happends when i include the header file in both a .c and a .cpp file?

Comment: Yes it matters. It's the `.cpp` or `.c` file that is the primary file being compiled and that's what IDE's and build systems look at to determine how to compile it.

Comment: Remember that an `#include` statement is simply bringing the content of the specified file into the content of the file that has the `#include` statement. So yes, if the header file is included by a `.c` file then the header code will be interpreted as C code, whereas if the header file is included by a `.cpp` or other C++ file then the header code will be interpreted as C++ code instead.