# C Enum reference undefined, yet sitting in a included header file?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, enums, gnutls

So, I'm playing with GNUTLS, and it has this enum:

```
typedef enum {
    GNUTLS_PK_UNKNOWN = 0,
    GNUTLS_PK_RSA = 1,
    GNUTLS_PK_DSA = 2,
    GNUTLS_PK_DH = 3,
    GNUTLS_PK_EC = 4
} gnutls_pk_algorithm_t;
```

sitting in it's main header file(gnutls.h, version 3.3.17). I reference it here:

```
    unsigned int bits = gnutls_sec_param_to_pk_bits(GNUTLS_PK_DH, GNUTLS_SEC_PARAM_LEGACY);
```

(right out of the example). I do have the `#include <gnutls/gnutls.h>`, and that all seems to reference fine(other enums are fine, except for `GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM`). I read something about the compiler not seeing gnutls.h, and it is in `/usr/local/include` and not `/usr/include`, however I do have that in the Includes side thing in Eclipse. If it is a compiler-not-finding-it, why is it finding some values, and how do I make it find it? If not, what is the issue?

Comment: @avaProphet I do not see the definition of that enumerator GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM in the enumeration you showed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's in another enum, should I add that in?

Comment: @avaProphet If the enumerations are defined in the same header then the compiler should see them.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I did GCC manually and it did not output an issue. I did a quick google and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866873/eclipse-cdt-c-enum-could-not-be-resolved which solved the issue. Feel free to post that as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how to find? add `-I/usr/local/include` to your gcc command line, or CFLAGS in the makefile, or look [here for how to add it in eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm)

If the compiler is finding some values while not finding the include, maybe they defined elsewhere. try to redefine them, and look in the error where the other definition is. 
to redefine you can declare as different type, (like: `typedef int whatever;`, to see if and where `whatever` declared) since if it is the same typedef it may considered as a forward deceleration.